# 7zip extract to cloudBerry Drive gives error 'cannot set length of output file. a device attached to the system is not functioning'

Tags: 7zip, cloudberry

Am using 7zip V 17.x GUI to extract files directly to CloudBerry Drive. For larger files >2GB, I get an error 'cannot set length of output file. a device attached to the system is not functioning'.

Is there a workaround in CloudBerry drive setting or in 7zip to fix this error.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution that the cloudBerry drive's temp/working folder is running out of space, hence 7-zip is not able to do the job. After changing  CloudBerry drive's temp/working folder directory via : Options -> Advanced -> File Cache Directory ,

the issue is solved.